# New to d3.js. Trying to back into this dendogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Index.html and Viz:** http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

**JSON File** https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288

All I want to be able to do, is learn how to add more nodes.

if one node is `{"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}`

If I add a comma after that and put the below

`{"name": "SpanningTree2", "size": 7312}`

should that not add another node? What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a good read of [ask]. Please do that first. Then move on to [mcve].

Comment: This is meant for javascript, not Java.9  I edited the post.

Comment: @Lasagna Does that exempt the OP of reading how to ask a question as per the Stack Overflow guidelines described in [ask]?

Comment: Did I say it does?  The OP can reword his question while it's sent to the proper place to be answered.  At least give the new guy a chance, people are so hard on people on this site for little mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It should, if the objects are inside an array:

```
[
    {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416},
    {"name": "SpanningTree2", "size": 7312}
]
```

Check if this is the case. Also, mind any trailing comma.